# Laravel 5.6 composer doesn't install my package's dependencies

Tags: laravel, composer-php, bitbucket

When i use "composer require x/y" command inside my custom package all done. Getting all dependencies perfectly.

But when i try to add to laravel project from bitbucket repository, only install my package without all dependencies.

I set my private repository to laravel composer.json file

```js
"repositories": {
    "hooks": {
        "type":"package",
        "package": {
            "name": "x/y",
            "version":"1.0.2",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://{username}@bitbucket.org/x/y.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom repository composer.json

```js
{
        "name": "x/y",
        "description": "Base Api System",
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.2",
            "tcg/voyager": "^1.1",
            "predis/predis": "1.1",
            "monarobase/country-list": "^2.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "X\\Y\\": "src/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "providers": [
                    "X\\Y\\XYServiceProvider"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Composer require output

```console
Using version ^1.0 for x/y
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing x/y (1.0.2): Cloning master from cache
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Comment: What does `composer show | grep monarobase` display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type incorrectly. This type is for non-composer packages. Composer will not even look at `composer.json` file in such dependency, since it assumes that this file does not exist. All relevant information about package should be in package definition in `repositories` setting in `composer.json` of main (root) application.

But in your case you have repository with complete composer package (with correct `composer.json` file), so you should `vcs` or `git` type:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"git",
        "url": "https://{username}@bitbucket.org/x/y.git"
    }
]
```